# Sqlite Database does not return correct values in my Java Spring Security application?

Tags: java, spring, sqlite, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a problem with SQLite and Spring Security. I have prepared my first application in Spring and I want use Spring Security with SQLite.
Here is my code:
Setup for database:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
            .and().csrf()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
}

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username,password,enabled from user where username=?");
}
```

database:

```
INSERT INTO user(username,password, enabled)
VALUES ('nequeq','123', 'true' );
INSERT INTO user(username,password, enabled)
VALUES ('alex','123', 'true');

INSERT INTO authorities (username, authority)
VALUES ('nequeq', 'ROLE_USER');
INSERT INTO authorities (username, authority)
VALUES ('nequeq', 'ROLE_ADMIN');
INSERT INTO authorities (username, authority)
VALUES ('alex', 'ROLE_USER');
```

login page:

```
<body>
<div id="mainWrapper">
<div class="login-container">
    <div class="login-card">
        <div class="login-form">
            <c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />
            <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <p>Invalid username and password.</p>
                    </div>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        <p>You have been logged out successfully.</p>
                    </div>
                </c:if>
                <div class="input-group input-sm">
                    <label class="input-group-addon" for="username"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="ssoId" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group input-sm">
                    <label class="input-group-addon" for="password"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"  value="${_csrf.token}" />

                <div class="form-actions">
                    <input type="submit"
                           class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-default" value="Log in">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is not full code, just most important part. Application works, I can see pages and whatever I want.
But I can not log into my system, always this code returns "Invalid username and password".

Could you help me with this?

Comment: Ok, I solved it. I missed bean with userdetailservice from Spring.